# Why would you scale a continues variable like age?

Tags: r, standardization

One of the analyst I work with has performed a propensity score analysis for us. Unfortunatly, he doesn't have the time to discuss the details as to why he has chosen to do certain things the way he has. One of the things was that he created a new variable he called "age_std" by scaling the age variable. He used this variable instead of age in the propensity score model.

What is a reason to do this?

I figured it had to do with creating a better 'balance' between the groups. But the truth is I don't know and google can't help me. So I was hoping you guys could. He did something similar to the year someone starts with a medicine. Decided to deduct the median from it.

This is the code.

```
dat$bio_drug_start_year_centered = dat$bio_drug_start_year - 
              median(dat$bio_drug_start_year)
dat$age_std = scale(dat$age)
```

Any explanation would be very welcome.

Comment: Such scaling accomplishes nothing but adding confusion, but it does demonstrate that the analyst is falsely assuming that age is linearly related to the log odds of propensity.  Bigger picture: propensity score analysis is unlikely to be a good idea in your situation (no matter what that situation is).

Comment: Some analysts just have this habit of scaling everything because it can help some models, and doesn't often hurt them much. However, I agree with the above comments; it adds confusion, and does suggest the analyst may not have done proper linearity tests.

Comment: Having estimators/algorithms being scale and shift invariant often leads to increased robustness/performance. The reason being that two degrees of freedom/noise are now removed, which leads to a decrease in the variance of the estimator. For example, for the conditional mean, a constant shift in the outcome corresponds with a constant shift in the conditional mean. Thus, it makes sense that a regression estimator should also satisfy this property. A number of algorithms are inherently shift/scale invariant, but by normalizing the covariates, one can always ensure that this is the case.

Comment: Though, I imagine this was not the motivation of the analyst (as linear regression is shift and scale invariant).